# CMake: can't find my header file in a different directory

Tags: c++, c, cmake, compiler-errors, header-files

I have a CMake project with these relevant folders:

```
project_folder
-src
|--main.c
peripherals
|--something.h
|--something.c
```

My CMake in `project_folder` includes:

```
add_subdirectory(peripherals)

if (NOT $ENV{TARGET_SOURCES} STREQUAL "")
    target_sources(app PRIVATE $ENV{TARGET_SOURCES})
else()
    target_sources(app PRIVATE src/main.c)
endif()
```

My CMake under `peripherals` incudes:

```
add_library (peripherals something.c)

target_include_directories (peripherals PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

CMake under `src`:

```
add_executable(app main.c)
target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE peripherals)
```

My project is building fully but when I try to include my header file in `main.c` I get:

```
project_folder/peripherals/something.h:No such file or directory
```

In my `main.c` file I have `#include "peripherals/something.h"`. Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm not sure if my #include statement is correct and I think I am missing stuff in my CMakeLists files

Comment: How does the CMakeLists.txt in `src` look like? Can you add all CMakeLists that you have in the folder structure?

Comment: @MikaelH Just updated with all my CMakeLists files

Comment: In that case, "app" should already have the includes of "peripherals" for free, no need to specify subfolders. Just as you include a file in something.c, you should be able to do the same in main.c.  Do you get an error when you only write include "something.h"  in main.c?

Comment: And I don't see the reason for using target_sources - you are already correctly specifying the source file (main.c) when you add the library.

Comment: How is the CMake file in `src` even found? Are you missing an `add_subdirectory(src)` call?

Comment: @squareskittles You're right, I forgot `add_subdirectory(src)` in my Cmakelist in `project_folder`. I just added it but now whenever I try to build I'm getting this error: 
`Attempt to add link library "peripherals" to target "app" which is not built in
  this directory. This is allowed only when policy CMP0079 is set to NEW.`
I changed cmakelists under src to just have `target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE peripherals)`.

Comment: @MikaelH Before I started adding these other files I had `target_sources(app PRIVATE src/main.c)`. And yes using this setup (where cmakelists under src is not even being called) I am only getting an error when I try to include my header file in main.c. However I don't know if there's something "fundamentally broken".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either do `"#include "../peripherals/i2c_test.h"` in your **main.cpp**

OR

in your CMake in `project_folder`:

```
 target_include_directories(app ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

and then in main.c:

```cpp
#include <peripherals/i2c_test.h>
....
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to define executable and "link" it with the library:

```
# project_folder/CMakeLists.txt
add_subdirectory(peripherals)
add_subdirectory(src)


# project_folder/src/CMakeLists.txt
add_executable(my_executable main.c)
target_link_libraries(my_executable PRIVATE peripherals)
```

Then, you'll need to include the header in `main.c` properly- since you've linked against a library that includes `peripherals` directory, you can now directly include it:

```
#include "something.h"
```

Comment: My `main.c` is already the target I believe, I have this in my CMakeLists for the overall project: ```target_sources(app PRIVATE src/main.c)```. Is it still necessary to add it as an executable again?

Comment: @Tracy As commented earlier, please show **all** of the relevant CMake code in your question post. Without seeing this, we are really only guessing at the problem...

Comment: @Tracy No, you don't have to redefine / add another target. The point is, you should link (as in `target_link_libraries`) your `app` target with the library defined in `peripherals`. This way, the publicly included directories for the `peripherals` library will also be included for the `app` target, allowing you to include headers from that directory like I've described above.

Answer (score 0):

Your include statement has to be relative to the included directory.

**Edit:** In your example `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` is the project directory (where your CMake file is).

Therefore you should be able to write:

```
#include <peripherals/something.h>
```

You can always check a cmake variable's content by printing it. In your CMake file you can write:

```
message(STATUS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

When running cmake you should see the path printed in the console output.

Comment: "*By default CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR is your working directory (form where you call cmake)*"... This is not always true. Maybe you're referring to `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`?

Answer (score 0):

in your CMake in project_folder:

```
 include_directories(src)
```

and then in main.c:

```c
#include <peripherals/i2c_test.h>
```

**OR**

in your CMake in project_folder:

```
 include_directories(src/peripherals)
```

and then in main.c:

```c
#include <i2c_test.h>
```